# Extracting Map from case class that has been initialized to an empty object

Tags: scala, global-variables, case-class

I have the following code piece (the below two lines are  **global**):

```
case class FeatureGraph(h: mutable.HashMap[String, String])
private var latestNode = FeatureGraph
```

Let us assume I have a method `setLatestNode` which sets `latestNode` to the corresponding `case class` with some `map`

Now, I want to access `latestNode` in another method. Let's say it is `performOperations`. It is given as below:

```
def performOperations = Unit {
  val operation = latestNode.h //This line shoots an error (h not found)
}
```

Is there any way to access latestNode's `HashMap` for these conditions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `private var latestNode = FeatureGraph` means `latestNode`'s type is `mutable.HashMap[String, String] => FeatureGraph`, which doesn't have a `.h` field. Do you mean something like `private var latestNode: FeatureGraph = _`?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu Yes, that did the trick! Thanks a bunch.